# Can not get url that contain "."

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a problem with react-router as the image bellow.

The problem seem to be caused by the "." in url. it can be fixed by using param instead but i still want to use this router format.

How can i fix it. Thanks

[image: The issue]

Comment: Which version of react-router are you using?

Comment: "react-router": "^2.7.0"

Comment: Can you show us your entire Router configuration with all the routes?

Comment: <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/login" component={LoginPage} onEnter={checkLogin}/>
    <Route path="/ForgotPassword" component={ForgotPassword}/>
    <Route path="/resetpassword(/:token)" component={ResetPassword}/>
</Router>